# How to get values from EditText on Button click using Data Binding in android?

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-databinding, android-mvvm

**activity_login.xml**
In my layout file there are total 3 fields. 2 edittext and 1 button
I want to get values from edittext on button click

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="LoginViewModel"
            type="com.example.ronil.viewmodel.LoginViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.ronil.view.activty.Login">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/tiet_emailid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="EmailId/MobileNo"
                android:text="@={LoginViewModel.userId}" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/tiet_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:text="@={LoginViewModel.password}" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/appbtn_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{LoginViewModel.onClickLogin}"
            android:text="Login" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

//Login.java

```
package com.example.ronil.view.activty;

import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.ronil.rx.R;
import com.example.ronil.rx.databinding.ActivityLoginBinding;
import com.example.ronil.viewmodel.LoginViewModel;
import com.example.ronil.viewmodel.interfaces.DownloadData;

import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements Observer {

    ActivityLoginBinding activityLoginBinding;
    LoginViewModel loginViewModel;

    private String TAG = "LOGINTAG";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initDataBinding();

        setUpObserver(loginViewModel);

    }



    public void initDataBinding() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initDataBinding: ");

        activityLoginBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login);
        loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel(getApplicationContext());
        activityLoginBinding.setLoginViewModel(loginViewModel);


    }



    public void setUpObserver(Observable observable) {
        observable.addObserver(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "setUpObserver: ");

    }



    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

    }

}
```

// LoginViewModel.java

How can i get userid and password from layout on button click
and what is difference between Observable and BaseObservable

```
package com.example.ronil.viewmodel;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.Observable;

public class LoginViewModel extends Observable {

    private Context context;


    public LoginViewModel(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public void onClickLogin(View view) {
        initializeViews();
    }

    private void initializeViews() {
    }

}
```

I am trying two-way data binding.
expecting UserID and Passowrd on Button Click and validate it before making network call